# change the mysql root password.How?

Tags: mysql, passwords, root

I am new to MySQL. I am trying to change the root credentials for Mysql. I searched for it on many sites but I didn't find anything. I tried it with the help of this [site](https://hostingga.com/blog/) blog. I thought it will help me because my error code was the same as mentioned in this blog. Please help me with this. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can update your password instead of YOUR PASSWORD HERE and execute query

update user set password = PASSWORD('YOUR PASSWORD HERE') where user='root';

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by cmd, just go to mysql dir and follow the below instructions.
Please check this link:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/679556/how-to-recover-mysql-password?noredirect=1&lq=1